# Query MySQL by checking multiple checkboxes with automatic update

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, checkbox

I would like to build a kind of advanced mySQL search - with the help of JQuery - where the user query the database by checking checkboxes and as a checkbox is checked a DIV is immediately updated via AJAX with the results. A kind of autocomplete but with checkboxes.

For example, I have two or more checkboxes as these:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Windows" name="system"> Windows
<input type="checkbox" id="Linux" name="system"> Linux
```

If the user checks "Windows" mySQL does immediately (without clicking any Submit button) return a list of Windows softwares. If the user checks both, mySQL should immediately return a list of Windows AND Linux softwares.

The following works fine for one choice but not for both:

```
<div id="update"></div>

$('input[name=system]').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    $.get("review.php", {param: id}, 
        function(data) {
            $("div#update").html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Review.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['param'])) {
    $param = $_GET['param'];
}
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE os = '".$param."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[name=system]').click(function(){

    var ids = [];
    $('input[name=system]:checked').each(function() {
        ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    ids = ids.join(",");

    $.get("review.php", {param: ids}, 
        function(data) {
            $("div#update").html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

And in your PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['param'])) {
    $param = "('" . str_replace(",", "','", $_GET['param']) . "')";
}
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE os IN $param") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Excellent! It worked immediately. I would never work it out by myself.

Comment: Glad i could help. If the answer helped you, do mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick icon above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one click function for both check-boxes which would check both (all) values and create one http request such as `?param=windows,linux`.

You also need to update condition in mysql query, so it'd look like:

```php
$params = explode( ',', $param);
// escape all params (mysql_real_escape_string)
$condition = 'os IN("' . implode( '", "', $params) . '")';
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE $condition") or die(mysql_error());
```